# Giving sprites an overlay in the Phaser framework

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm trying to have a certain scene in my game where all of the game sprites have a gray overlay on them. I thought about just creating a gray version of each sprite, but then I realized that is not very DRY or easy. I need this overlay for both a singular sprite, like so:

```
sprite = game.add.sprite(x, y, "name_of_sprite");
```

And I need it for a group:

```
group = game.add.group();
```

How do you this in context of `phaser`?

Comment: please somebody answer this question.. i also in need with the solution. thanks

Comment: @Vainglory07 I was able to find an answer for this question

Comment: wooo finally :D thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either one of these solutions will do the trick:

[Sprite tinting](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/sprite-tint)

```
yourSpriteName.tint = color;
```

[Gray filter example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/filters/gray)

```
var gray = game.add.filter("Gray");

yourSpriteName.filters = [gray];
```

Comment: i used the first one. pretty much easy. while the second option is not working for me. idk why, i tried the blur one, it's working fine. btw thanks

Comment: @Vainglory07: Filters is only supported in WebGL mode.